# Using jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut with radio list filter, but fades repeat twice instead of once

Tags: jquery

I am making a page that has a list of games. I added radio buttons that filter the games by genre. I am using jQuery to elegantly fade the list of games in and out as the user clicks through the genre filter.

The issue is that each time you click on a radio button, the game list awkwardly fades in and out twice. See: http://jsfiddle.net/animeguy99/pZKda/1/

Here is the script I'm using:

```
$('input[name$="group1"]').click(function(){
    var radio_value = $(this).val();    
    if(radio_value=='Adventure') {
      $('#games div').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#games .adv').fadeIn();
      });
    }
    else if(radio_value=='Puzzle') {
      $('#games div').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#games .puz').fadeIn();
      });
    }
    else if(radio_value=='Shooter') {
      $('#games div').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#games .sho').fadeIn();
      });
    }
    else if(radio_value=='All') {
      $('#games div').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#games div').fadeIn();
      });
    }
});
```

I have the genre types declared by DIV classes. So each time the user clicks a radio, I am fading out all DIVs (the games) and then fade in the requested genre by DIV class.

When I Googled around, similar cases suggested this could be a parent/child issue. But I'm puzzled as to how to relate that to my script.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback function to `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` does not work the way you might expect when there are multiple elements being faded. The callback is called not just once, but for *every element*.

If you put a `console.log()` call in one of the `.fadeOut()` callbacks, you will see that it gets logged multiple times. (The Chrome developer tools collapse this to a single log entry with a number to the left.)

http://jqapi.com/#p=fadeOut

> #### Callback Function
>
> If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different animations together in sequence. The callback is not sent any arguments, but this is set to the DOM element being animated. If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.
>
> As of jQuery 1.6, the .promise() method can be used in conjunction with the deferred.done() method to execute a single callback for the animation as a whole when all matching elements have completed their animations ( See the example for .promise() ).

Here's a version of your code that uses `.promise()` to remove the duplicate callbacks. It also incorporates j08691's suggestion to exclude from the fadeOut the elements that you will be fading in:

```
var groups = {
    Adventure: '.adv',
    Puzzle: '.puz',
    Shooter: '.sho',
    All: 'div'
};

function fade( group ) {
    $('#games div')
        .not(group)
        .fadeOut()
        .promise()
        .done( function() {
            console.log( group );
            $('#games ' + group).fadeIn();
        });
}

$('input[name$="group1"]').click(function () {
    fade( groups[ $(this).val() ] );
});
```

This code is also simplified considerably over the original, by combining duplicate code into a single function. Finally, I left in a console.log() to view the calls being made.

Also a couple of comments on the HTML: You don't need to use `<br />` unless you're writing XHTML, which I hope you're not doing. `<br>` is fine. More importantly, you should use `<label>` tags on the radio button labels so the entire label is clickable:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="All" checked>Show All</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Adventure">Adventure</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Puzzle">Puzzle</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Shooter">Shooter</label>
```

Here's an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAGNX/1/).

There are additional opportunities for simplification here as well. Is it a requirement that the `value` attributes in your radio buttons be the specific strings 'All', 'Adventure', etc.? If not, you could simply put the group selectors directly in the `value` attributes:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" value="div" checked>Show All</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" value=".adv">Adventure</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" value=".puz">Puzzle</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="group1" value=".sho">Shooter</label>
```

And then the JavaScript code is simplified to:

```
function fade( group ) {
    $('#games div')
        .not(group)
        .fadeOut()
        .promise()
        .done( function() {
            console.log( group );
            $('#games ' + group).fadeIn();
        });
}

$('input[name$="group1"]').click(function () {
    fade( $(this).val() );
});
```

[Latest jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAGNX/3/)

Another update... As Alex points out in a comment, this version of the code causes blocks to jump around when you click back and forth between Show All and specific genres.

That's caused by this line in the code:

```
        .not(group)
```

Removing that line gives smoother transitions, as shown in this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAGNX/4/).

Comment: I've been reading and re-reading your post. I need to take some time to study and absorb all of this because you're entering uncharted territory for me. I'm just a designer with basic knowledge of jQuery. I need to research **console.log()** and **.promise()**; I've never heard of them before.

Comment: Cool, I am happy to assist with your new adventure. `console.log()` is great, but I should have mentioned how you can view its messages: Open your browser's developer tools and select the Console. (In Chrome it's under the Tools menu.) There are all sorts of other great tools there, for example you can add a `debugger;` statement to your code and it will stop right there in the JavaScript debugger, where you can view and change variables, etc. Give a shout with any questions!

Comment: I've continued studying your post (as well as everyone else's here). I now understand `console.log()` and the value of it. I've started using it already regularly in my scripts. I've found that every console in every browser supports it! Although I'm still studying `.promise()` and `.done()`. I understand what it does, but not enough to know when to use it in my scripts.

Comment: I have one more request from you. While your script makes a clean/simplified/perfect backend, on the frontend there's a slight issue. As you're clicking through the radio buttons, jumping to and from "Show All" causes DIVs to jump around instead of fade. Do you mind creating one more jsfiddle that resolves that? I've been trying to figure it out on my own, but I don't have enough familiarity yet with simplified coding. My current level of jQuery scripting wants to solve everything with IF statements.

Comment: Sure, I just updated the answer. It's easier than you might suspect: simply delete the `.not(group)` line.

Comment: And very glad to hear you're exploring `console.log()` and the other debugging tools. That will make it so much easier to troubleshoot problems. If you didn't try it yet, the next thing is to add a `debugger;` statement anywhere in your code, then load the page and get it to run that part of your code. It will stop in the JavaScript debugger and show you things like your local variables. You can then hover the mouse over anything in the code and it will show you the value of whatever you point to. And you can single step through your code to see what happens when it runs. Very powerful!

Comment: Wow, it's beautiful!! Thank you very much! **Best answer** and beyond! I've impressed the .NET developers at my job with what I learned in this thread. Although this jQuery script in particular is for play not for work; for a new section in my classic gaming hobby site. `debugger;` sounds awesome. I will explore it. I had no idea jQuery came equipped with these features. A whole new world is opened up to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this fiddle.
The issue is with your jQuery Selector `$('#games div')`. Your selection points to multiple DOM elements. So it will run `fadeOut()` for every element in scope and then on the callback for every element run `fadeIn()`. Adding an additional selector would ensure that it runs only once.

```
$('#games div').filter(":visible")
```

Adding the `.filter(":visible")` limit will ensure that only those which are visible should be faded out (if the filter is not used than if any element of the selection is hidden it will fire the `fadeIn()` immediately). And it will also ensure that `fadeIn()` only runs once all the elements in selection that are visible are now hidden.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZKda/8/)

Comment: Thank you!! I see. So I just needed to be more specific with my selections.

Comment: There is a bit more to it than that. In particular, your `.fadeIn()` calls are still being made multiple times. Also you can simplify your code quite a lot by combining duplicate code into a single function. And there are some things you should change in your HTML too. Please see my answer for details.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Couldn't agree with you more. I am all for simplifying code. People really need to explore the new additions to DOM and client-side scripting. The code should be minimal yet easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude the group of elements from fading out first (via something like `.not('.puz')`), otherwise jQuery will make them visible again first, and then fade them out. Try this (delay added for clarity):

```
$('input[name$="group1"]').click(function () {
    var radio_value = $(this).val();
    if (radio_value == 'Adventure') {
        $('#games div').not('.adv').fadeOut(3000,function () {
            $('#games .adv').fadeIn(3000);
        });
    } else if (radio_value == 'Puzzle') {
        $('#games div').not('.puz').fadeOut(3000,function () {
            $('#games .puz').fadeIn(3000);
        });
    } else if (radio_value == 'Shooter') {
        $('#games div').not('.sho').fadeOut(3000,function () {
            $('#games .sho').fadeIn(3000);
        });
    } else if (radio_value == 'All') {
        $('#games div').fadeOut(3000, function () {
            $('#games div').fadeIn(3000);
        });
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pZKda/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call the fadeOut on the several elements, it gets called as many times. And your callback that triggers the fadeIn gets called the same number of times. You don't need that. You need to start calling fadeIn only when all fadeOuts are done.

One of the ways to do that is to use $.when .. $ done sequence:

```
$.when(
   $('#games div').fadeOut('slow');

).done(function() {
   $('#games .adv').fadeIn();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ 
http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

Answer (score 0):

Simple to do if you use html5 data type attribute. Checkout `jsfiddle`.